# Check if words from a file occur in a SQL query in an efficient way

Tags: python, sql, string, python-2.7, sqlite

I have a .txt file with words and small phrases separated by `,` and I wish to see which of these words occur in each row returned by
 `for line in cur.execute("select text from reviews where business_id = (?) ", (s,)):` (s takes values from an outer for loop).
My goal is to add +1 to a counter whenever a word from the .txt file is occuring in the rows returned by the SQL query (these rows are string of varying sizes, usually big enough to make slicing them and checking each word seperately time-consuming).
Is there another way to do so?
What I've tried:

```
for words in line:
   with open("good_words.txt", "r") as check:
     for x in check:
        if x in words:
        goods += 1
```

Which leads to my PC burning up and basically crushing.

Comment: You could turn the words into regular expressions, and then use a regexp search for them.

Comment: Turn every word and phrase in a RegEx and have multiple if-then-else statements? That would be just as time-consuming but I will try it.

Comment: `for words in line:` iterates over the characters in `line`, not the words. It should be `for words in line.split()`

Comment: No `if/then/else` statements, just a `for` loop that iterates over all the regexps.

Comment: @Barmar how can I split tuples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read all the words and phrases into a list of regexps.

```
good_words = []
with open("good_words.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        good_words.append(re.compile(r'\b' + re.escape(line) + r'\b'))
for line in cur.execute("select text from reviews where business_id = (?) ", (s,)):
    for word in good_words:
        if word.search(line[0]):
            goods += 1
```

`\b` matches word boundaries, so you don't have to split up the line into words.